# How do I execute jQuery promises in phantomJS?

Tags: jquery, node.js, phantomjs

I'm using trying to use nodejs and phantomjs on the server-side for SEO of our site. While ajax works fine, I'm not able to execute custom promises that I've used in my code. How do I make phantomJS wait till the promises are resolved.
Below is what I have coded.

```
$('body').addClass('before-dom-ready');

$(function() {
    $('body').addClass('after-dom-ready');

    var dfrd = $.Deferred(),
            promise = dfrd.promise();

    setTimeout(function() {
        dfrd.resolve();
    }, 5000);

    promise.done(function() {
        $('body').addClass('promise-executed');
    });

});
```

phantomJS adds 'before-dom-ready' and 'after-dom-ready' class, but I'm unable to get 'promise-executed' class on body.

Comment: Is it possible to see your full phantomJS script (as well as the full code of any other files it depends on). I.e. so we can easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: At what point in time, and how, are you checking to see if the `promise-executed` class has or has not been added? What kind of debugging have you done, for instance, have you tried placing a `console.log` call after the `dfrd.resolve()`? Have you tried this code in a regular browser, in other words, what makes you think it's a PhantomJS problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhantomJs does not automatically wait the end of all pending scripts.  WebPage#onLoadFinished is called on the onload event.

As for most of the scripts, the idea here is to wait until "something" is done or true.
I highly suggest you to test [waitfor.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js). It is really important to understand this example in PhantomJs.

I suppose your example is an example, but let me propose an answer.

**Html Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body id="body">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //alert('hello');
        $('body').addClass('before-dom-ready');

        $(function () {
            $('body').addClass('after-dom-ready');

            var dfrd = $.Deferred(),
                    promise = dfrd.promise();

            setTimeout(function () {
                dfrd.resolve();
            }, 5000);

            promise.done(function () {
                $('body').addClass('promise-executed');
                $('body').text('Hello World !');
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PhantomJs Script**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 10000, //< Default Max Timout is 10s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof (testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if (!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    //console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    typeof (onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady();
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    //phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof (onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 500); //< repeat check every 500ms
};

if (system.args.length != 1) {
    console.log('invalid call');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    //adapt url to your context
    page.open('http://localhost:9231/demo.html', function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            waitFor(
                function () {
                    return page.evaluate(function () {
                        return $('body').hasClass('promise-executed');
                    }) > 0;
                },
                function () {
                    page.render('page.png');
                    phantom.exit();
                }, 10000);
        }
    });
}
```

Basically, `waitFor` will check every 500 ms if body has a class named `'promise-executed'`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.. I'll have to do a bit more reading before incorporating into my tests, but this seems reasonable and well documented..